# Google OR, Time Window constraints

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a TSP problem using time window constraints. I have looked at the Google OR website (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw) and used their code but used my durations matrix and time windows. I dont see any difference in their format and mine and still my code wont come with a solution. I will provide the function I wrote for the data below, the rest of the code is exactly the same as in the example on Google OR (provided website link).

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import pandas as pd

customer_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/westm/OneDrive/Documenten/customers.csv')
durations_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/westm/OneDrive/Documenten/durations.csv')

def create_data_model():
    
    
    # Extract time window columns
    customer_timewindow = customer_data.iloc[:, [3, 4]]

    # Conversion function to convert time windows to tuples in the required format
    def convert_to_tuples(row):
        start_time = int(row['TW Start'].split(':')[0])
        end_time = int(row['TW End'].split(':')[0])
        return start_time, end_time

    # Apply the conversion function to each row of the customer time window data
    time_windows_tuples = customer_timewindow.apply(convert_to_tuples, axis=1)

    # Convert the result to a list of tuples
    time_windows_list = time_windows_tuples.tolist()
    time_windows_list.insert(0, (0, 24))

    # Drop the 'Unnamed: 0' column if not needed
    durations_data_adj = durations_data.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])

    customer_demand_list = customer_data.iloc[:, 7].tolist()

    indices_to_delete = []
    for i in range(len(customer_demand_list)):
        if customer_demand_list[i] == 0.0:
            indices_to_delete.append(i)

    # Remove corresponding rows and columns in durations_data_adj
    durations_data_adj = durations_data_adj.drop(durations_data_adj.index[indices_to_delete], axis=0)
    durations_data_adj = durations_data_adj.drop(durations_data_adj.columns[indices_to_delete], axis=1)

    # Remove corresponding entries in time_windows_list
    time_windows_list = [time_windows_list[i] for i in range(len(time_windows_list)) if i not in indices_to_delete]

    # Update customer_demand_list after removing zeros
    customer_demand_list = [demand for i, demand in enumerate(customer_demand_list) if i not in indices_to_delete]

    durations_list = [durations_data_adj.iloc[i].tolist() for i in range(len(durations_data_adj))]
    customer_demand_list = [0] + customer_demand_list

    data = {}
    
    data["time_matrix"] = durations_list
    
    data["time_windows"] = time_windows_list
    
    data["num_vehicles"] = 4
    data["depot"] = 0
    return data
```

durations_list is obtained from a standard durations matrix, where then ofcourse the diagonal is 0.
time_windows_list is obtained from columns 3,4 from customer_data.

I tried to change the number of vehicles (I dont know upfront how many I want) but that did not seem to work. Further also tried to ask chatGPt but that also did not lead to the solution.